# How to delete defined value from the begining of character in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table in Oracle SQL like below:

```
col1
--------
ABC|1234
ABC|55674
ABC|11
```

So I have in col1:

- always "ABC|" at the begining of each value
- different length of values after "ABC|"

I need result like below, so I need to delete "ABC|" from begining of each value

```
col1
---------------
1234
55674
11
```

How can I do that in Oracle SQL ?

Comment: A simple `REPLACE` would work if it is always the same string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple substring operation might be easiest here:

```sql
SELECT col1, SUBSTR(col1, 5) AS col1_out
FROM yourTable;
```

You could also do a replacement:

```sql
SELECT col1, REPLACE(col1, 'ABC|', '') AS col1_out
FROM yourTable;
```